# How to remove the bottom line of the tag <a>, in webforms c#

Tags: c#, html, css, webforms

I'm using webfroms, the problem is that I can't remove the bottom line from the a tag, I'm using text-decoration: none, but it doesn't work.

```
.item1 li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
     
}

.item1 li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:medium;
    text-align:justify;
}

.item1 li:hover{
    background:#555555;
    color:black;
}
```

```
 <div class="item1">
    <nav runat="server">
     <ul runat="server">
        <li id="liGenerarOficioSubsane" runat="server"><a href="#" runat="server">Generar Oficio de Subsane</a></li>
        <li id="liGenerarOficioConsulta" runat="server"><a href="#" runat="server">Generar Oficio de Consulta</a></li>
        <li id="liSegExpediente" runat="server"><a href="#" runat="server">Seguimiento de expediente</a></li>
        <li id="liSalidasCampo" runat="server"><a href="#" runat="server">Salidas al Campo</a></li>
        <li id="liReporteGiras" runat="server"><a href="#" runat="server">Reporte de Giras</a></li>
        <li id="liApelacionesRevoca" runat="server"><a href="#" runat="server">Registrar documentos por Apelación y-o revocatoria</a></li>
       </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

[image: I need remove buttom line of the tag]

Comment: Hi alberto, where did you applied `item1` class in your html. In your question, there is no `item1` class in html

Comment: hi, Ritu, the div have the class, I forgot to place the div, but it doesn't work

Comment: Your code works fine for me after you added `item1` class. Could you cross check it once again?

Comment: I do not know if it is the tag <a> that generates those lines

Comment: Isn't your code working for you?

Comment: Ritu, still does not work

Comment: add border-bottom: none, now works

Comment: Thanks, Ritu, in html5 with text-decoration:none remove the underline, I'm confused, but the important thing is that it works

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
.item1 li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color:black;
    font-size:medium;
    text-align:justify;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```